# stored columns in array but I can not show data

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to store in an array the data of the method Buscarme that is in the model, and then in the view, print the data.

this is model/cliente.php

```
<?php
class cliente
{
    private $pdo;
    public $id;
    public $resultado;
    public $dni;
    public $Nombre;
    public $Apellido;  
    public $Correo;
    public $Telefono;
    public $res;

    public function __CONSTRUCT(){
        try{
            $this->pdo = conectar();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function Buscarme($dni){
        try {
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE dni = :dni");
            $stm->bindParam(':dni', $dni, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->execute();    
            $res = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $resultado = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach($res as $row){
                $resultado[$i]['id']       = $row['id'];
                $resultado[$i]['dni']      = $row['dni'];
                $resultado[$i]['Nombre']   = $row['Nombre'] ;
                $resultado[$i]['Apellido'] = $row['Apellido'];
                $resultado[$i]['Correo']   = $row['Correo'] ;
                $resultado[$i]['Telefono'] = $row['Telefono'] ;
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

this view view/cliente/cliente.php

```
<h1 class="page-header">CRUD con el patrón MVC en PHP POO y PDO </h1>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&  =agregar">Agregar</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=ardila">Ardila</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=mateus">Mateus</a>
<br><br><br>
<table class="table  table-striped  table-hover" id="tabla">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">ID</th>
<th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">DNI</th>
<th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Nombre</th>
    <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Apellido</th>
    <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Correo</th>
 <th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD;  color:#fff">Telefono</th>            
    <th style="width:60px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff"></th>
    <th style="width:60px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($this->model->Listar() as $r): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $r->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->dni; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->Nombre; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->Apellido; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->Correo; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->Telefono; ?></td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table> 
<form action="?c=cliente&a=buscame" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="dni" id="dni"/>
<input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton"/>
</form>
<?php 
$this->model->Buscarme($_POST['dni']);
$resultado =  $this->model->resultado;
print_r($resultado);
?> 
</tbody>
</body>
<script  src="assets/js/datatable.js">  
</script>
</html>
```

When printing the data in the model are shown in the upper left of the page, the data should only be displayed below the search button

Comment: Question one does the html validate on w3c -> https://validator.w3.org/ .. Unvalidated html can cause displaying problems..

Comment: At first look the `print_r($resultado);` (and other php code) is within the html element `<tbody>` where it doesn't belong.. i think if you place it under the tag `</tbody>` that your display problem is solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the existing table data - from - `$this->model->Listar()` - to from - `$this->model->Buscarme($_POST['dni'])`

Fixed the table layout so that the page displays properly and records show below the search form.

Updated `view/cliente/cliente.php`.

**Try this:**

```
<h1 class="page-header">CRUD con el patrón MVC en PHP POO y PDO </h1>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&  =agregar">Agregar</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=ardila">Ardila</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=mateus">Mateus</a>
<br><br><br>
<table>
<form action="?c=cliente&a=buscame" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="dni" id="dni"/>
<input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton"/>
</form>
</table>

<table class="table  table-striped  table-hover" id="tabla">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">ID</th>
<th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">DNI</th>
<th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Nombre</th>
    <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Apellido</th>
    <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Correo</th>
 <th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD;  color:#fff">Telefono</th>            
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$this->model->Buscarme($_POST['dni']);
$resultado =  $this->model->resultado;
//print_r($resultado);
?> 
<?php foreach($resultado as $r): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $r['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['dni']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['Nombre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['Apellido']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['Correo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r['Telefono']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table> 

</body>
<script  src="assets/js/datatable.js">  
</script>
</html>
```

We were storing return data in a function variable rather than class variable. Fixed it. Also counter variable $i wasn't incrementing, made it increment by 1 each repetition.

`model/cliente.php`

**Updated function:**

```
public function Buscarme($dni){
        try {
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE dni = :dni");
            $stm->bindParam(':dni', $dni, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stm->execute();    
            $res = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->resultado = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach($res as $row){
                $this->resultado[$i]['id']       = $row['id'];
                $this->resultado[$i]['dni']      = $row['dni'];
                $this->resultado[$i]['Nombre']   = $row['Nombre'] ;
                $this->resultado[$i]['Apellido'] = $row['Apellido'];
                $this->resultado[$i]['Correo']   = $row['Correo'] ;
                $this->resultado[$i]['Telefono'] = $row['Telefono'] ;
                $i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: shows the error in invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc2\view\cliente\cliente.php on line 29